# building a service with an android app, an iOS app, and an API backend, all of which access the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, rest, api, authentication, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to build a server with a rest api and database.
it has ios and android clients, where you can log in with facebook.
the server can receive the access token that the clients get when they log in for the first time, and send it to the server. the server stores it in the database.
now the server can make graph api calls on the clients behalf.

but here's my question:

the next time the client asks the server to do something on it's behalf, what info must it send so that the server knows who the client is? is it just the access token again?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just the access token is enough to uniquely identify the user and the app.
You could try it by hitting graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me?fields=id&access_token=... with different tokens to check which user it is and whether the token is still valid.

Off topic, but since you're already using the server as the middle-man for your requests, I suggest using the code flow instead of token flow for added security: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#appsecret